# Where is the documentation for MVVM Light?

Tags: mvvm-light

Is there documentation or a reference for the MVVM Light framework that let me know what is it capable of? After a lot of googling I've found very few things.

Comment: I suppose you already checked [there](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation)?

Comment: Yes, and thank you. However, I feel this is not the full documentation as I'm not able to determine if MVVM Light has a given functionality. There is really no official documentation?

Comment: To my knowledge, the only official documentation is the source code.

Comment: Thank you Frederick & Obalix... now seems clear to me that learning MVVM Light has some unnecessary high curve... for me. Frédéric, please post something as an answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: About the unnecessary high curve, I think the mvvm pattern is more of a mindshift for most people(even though it's quite simple once you figured it out). I find the mvvm light toolkit simply helps easing out the mvvm learning curve other than making it harder to learn. Also, fyi, you can simply upvote  someone's comment if you want to give him points, no need for him to post an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Oxenon... how do I upvote a comment?

Comment: just mouse over the left margin of the comment and you'll see a flag (to report bad comments/spam) and a up-arrow (to upvvote).

Comment: I see... "this is a great comment" gives the points?

Comment: Exactly! and the flag reports the comment as spam or unconstructive, I dont know if it makes lose points though.

Comment: Good to know... you're very kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary documentation source is [MVVM Light's website](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). Additional, documentation in form of problem solutions can be found right here on Stack Overflow. Also looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight) might help.

Personally, I think that both Laurent's presentation at MIX'10 and Josh Smith's article are best to start.

However, there is no explicit documentation for two reasons:

1. It is a free tool and writing extended documentation is a time-consuming task.
2. Nobody has volunteered to do so.

There is some documentation in the source code that could be extracted by using `SandCastle`, but I believe that the classes are reasonably self-documenting. Furthermore, in all the time I used MVVM Light I did not have the need for additional documentation, other than the documentation provided by the two sites above and the problem solutions here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm a little lost here... as you, Frédéric, appears "included" in Obalix answers does that means you "inherit" the points? Sorry, not fully used to this site functionality.

Comment: Frédéric just corrected some of my spelling errors, and improved the wording (@Frédéric Hamidi: thank's). The points overlap as there are - as described in the answer - not many places where to find documentation. Although, there are overlaps with his comments, I decided to post a proper answer to make it more formal. Additionally, I wanted to share my experience with learning MVVM Light. Actually, I when writing the post I did not look at Frédéric's comments, but it is more or less common knowledge.

Comment: That the product is free and that writing documentation is time-consuming are somewhat orthogonal.  The quality of the documentation is down to the importance that a developer attaches to usability.

Comment: MVVM Light is not maintained anymore, and the first link is dead. The github page links to [the microsoft MVVM toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, no there is no official documentation for the mvvm light toolkit, but I will give you the links I used myself and they were more than enough for me.

Those two conferences from laurent demonstrate the main uses of the toolkit along with   general mvvm presentation. I found them really interesting and would recommend watching them if you are looking for what this toolkit is capable of.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX14 and
http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

Also:

http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old, but I just stumbled over the same issue. The API docs for all platforms and as HTML and CHM are located here: http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/

Comment: But not anymore.

Comment: @jwrush Indeed, the link on the website also points to this though. I pinged the author to check if it's maybe only temporary