# Is there a list somewhere of all the tools MVVM light toolkit provide you with?

Tags: mvvm-light

so I have been using the MVVM-light toolkit on a project that I am working on and I really like it.

I have used ViewModelLocator, SimpleIOC, design time data and relay commands, but i was curious if there is something else that i have missed. So what I am looking for is like list of the core tools that the toolkit provide so I can google it learn more about them.

I tried to find a decent documentation, I know about the pluralsight doc(http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvvm-light-toolkit-fundamentals), but I don't have a subscription and this explains why there isn't a good free one [Where is the documentation for MVVM Light?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000673/where-is-the-documentation-for-mvvm-light).

I hope this isn't a too stupid question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse all of the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.* classes in Visual Studio's Object Browser and make sure you know what is the purpose of each of them. In case of doubt look at http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/ or ask a question on SO.

Comment: I thought for sure this question had gone into the abyss. Thanks, will do :)